What can I do when getting "type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast" in flutter when i want to output list of values?

i have the error of "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast" when ever i pass data of summary question widget to the result screen widget
i was expecting to view the result of my dummy data
can you help?
this image is displayed error.
questions_summar.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QuestionsSummary extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuestionsSummary(this.sumaryData, {super.key});

  final List<Map<String, Object>> sumaryData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: sumaryData.map((data) {
        return Row(children: [
          Text(((data['question_index'] as int) + 1).toString()),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(data['question'] as String),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                Text(data['user_answer'] as String),
                Text(data['correct_answer'] as String),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

results_screen.dart
import 'package:app2/data/questions.dart';
import 'package:app2/questions_summary.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResultsSscreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResultsSscreen({required this.chosenAnswers, super.key});

  final List<String> chosenAnswers;

  List<Map<String, Object>> getSummaryData() {
    final List<Map<String, Object>> summary = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < chosenAnswers.length; i++) {
      summary.add({
        'question_index': i,
        'question': questions[i].answers,
        'correct_answer': questions[i].answers[0],
        'user_answer': chosenAnswers[i]
      });
    }
    return summary;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(35),
          child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            const Text('You answered some out of more correctly'),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            QuestionsSummary(getSummaryData()),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Restart Quiz'))
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you share a minimal code snippet of your issue?

I think one of your fields which you set as as String is a list of strings not a string. This line may be the cause of the error:  'question': questions[i].answers,

thanks for the hint: the correct way was 'question': questions[i].question,`
